# How can I tell the resistance of an internal pull-up resistor?

Tags: esp8266, voltage-level, input, resistor, pull-up

I have a SparkFun ESP8266 Thing Dev board, to which I want to perform a `digitalRead()` on one of the GPIO ports. I'm using `D15`, and I'm configuring it for input like this

```
pinMode(15, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

It does seem to work as intended, and I am able to pull it down by connecting it to ground via a 4.7kΩ resistor.

But how do I know what the actual "correct" resistor would be? I can't find any specs for the internal pullup resistor online. On a related note, I first tried using `D0`, but it didn't seem to have an internal pullup resistor, since even using `INPUT_PULLUP` didn't turn it on.

Perhaps there are specs online and I'm just not able to find them, but is there any other way (measuring?) to find out which pins will work with `INPUT_PULLUP` and if so, what their internal resistance is?

Comment: What makes you believe that you need a resistor at all?

Comment: You may find this edifying though: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/measuring-arduino-internal-pull-resistors

Comment: Internal pullup resistor only gives the pin a definite input value (HIGH) if it is floating. If the pin is connected to ground then it will read LOW, regardless of whether a pullup resistor is used or not.

Comment: @gandalf61 Won't that depend on the ratio between the pullup and pulldown resistors? Of course if it's connected directly to ground, then it would definitely be low...

Comment: @Majenko Hmm... is it safe to connect a GPIO input directly to +5V or ground, without any resistor? Won't it draw an unnecessarily high current, and/or risk damaging something in the device?

Comment: D0 is io 16. it has internal pulldown. I know it from the esp8266 Arduino package online documentation

Comment: @Majenko I guess I got a bit worried about connecting anything directly to the pins since some seem to be used for various things, and some (at least the internal LED, `D5`) seem to be inverted (setting it to `HIGH` will turn off the LED, and `LOW` turns it on)... on the normal Arduino things seem more straightforward.

Comment: You can only do damage if the pin is set to output. When input there is nothing to damage. It is common to add a very small (100r or so) resistor in series with the output to protect it just in case.

Comment: @Juraj Hmm, by `D0` I mean the pin labeled `0` on the board, and referred to as `0` and `D0` in the pin overview image from SparkFun. Where exactly do you get `16` from? Either way, I can't seem to get that pin to work as expected, it might be because the docs say it's "Used in reset"....

Comment: right, io 0 is a boot configuration pin. it should have an external pull-up on board (NodeMcu and Wemos/Lolin have Dx labeled pins. you confused me with the D)

Comment: @MagnusW `directly to +5V` on an ESP8266, I'd limit that to +3.3V - as much as I've read that the GPIO are "5v tolerant" I'd stick to 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

io 0 and io 15 are with io 2 boot configuration pins of the esp8266. esp8266 dev boards have external pull-up on io 0 and io 2 and pull-down on io 15.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find this information? The [Hookup Guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-development-board-hookup-guide/all) I found doesn't really say much about pins 0, 4 and 15... and SparkFuns own examples seem to mostly use pin 12 as `INPUT_PULLUP`, which is the only one I got it to work with.

Comment: the best source is Espressif's site (esp8266_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf). but the information about boot pins is on many web pages about esp8266

Comment: Hmm, now I'm feeling a bit stupid... when I say `pinMode(12, INPUT)` - does the `12` refer to GPIO12 or to "pin 12", which in the [Espressif Hardware Design Guidelines](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8266_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf) means GPIO13? It gets even more confusing when [the SparkFun pin guideline](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/4/4/5/esp8266-thing-pinout.png) refers to pin 12 as D12... Which one of all of these am I really interested in when calling `pinMode()`??

Comment: in Sparkfun Thing the labels and the pin numbers (even if prefixed with D) correspond to gpio numbers used by Espressif. (NodeMcu and Wemos/Lolin boards have Dx comstants and labels)

Answer (score 0):

"The value of internal (built-in) pull-up resistor is between 30Kohm and 100Kohm."

Source: https://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=1079#p4097

Comment: did you read the accepted answer?